# LINQ to XML Question: Returning Nodes with a particular select

Tags: xml, linq, .net-3.5, select

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <ConfiguraCanale ID_Comando="1">
        <canaleDigitalOUTPUT ID_Canale="1" >
            <stato>0</stato>
        </canaleDigitalOUTPUT>
    </ConfiguraCanale>


    <ConfiguraCanale ID_Comando="2">
        <canaleAnalogicoINPUT ID_Canale="2">                
            <timeAttesaPreCamp>00:03:00</timeAttesaPreCamp> 
        </canaleAnalogicoINPUT>
    </ConfiguraCanale>      

    </Comandi>
```

I must select the node canaleAnalogicoINPUT, and it's simple, but I must also take ID_Comando from ConfiguraCanale up to canaleAnalogicoINPUT.. because I select the node canaleAnalogicoINPUT I can't get attribute of the node ConfiguraCanale.

I use Linq to XML from few time...

Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why don't you make 2 selections, one for ConfiguraCanale (and extract ID_Comando) and one for canaleAnalogicoINPUT? Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something like this:

```
var inputs = from e in doc.Descendants("canaleAnalogicoINPUT")
             select new
             {
                 CanaleAnalogicoINPUT = e, // extract what you need from this node
                 IDComando = int.Parse(e.Parent.Attribute("ID_Comando").Value)
             };
```

Comment: I resolve with 
                                           
ID_Comando = canale.Parent.Attribute("ID_Comando").Value

In this case also FirstAttribute is good:
ID_Comando = canale.Parent.FirstAttribute.Value, 

PARENT was the solution... I must study more! :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = from e in doc.Elements("ConfiguraCanale")
             select new 
             {
                 IDComando = e.Attribute("ID_Comando").Value,
                 CanaleAnalogicoINPUT = e.Element("canaleAnalogicoINPUT")
             };
```